# My HTML5 audio tag does not play in Google Chrome.

Tags: html, audio

I have a simple audio "streaming" service on my website. I am streaming from SHOUTcast's IP address which is provided and the audio type is currently in AACP.

Here is my code:

`<audio id="audioplayer" controls autoplay>
     <source src="http://50.7.77.114:8007/" type="audio/aacp">
 </audio>`

The streaming service has been working flawlessly for around a year and a bit without a problem.

Now it does not play and does not show an error. Is there a bug with Google Chrome that we don't know of by any chance?

I'm using Google Chrome: **Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e32cyrs9/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stream stopped working in Chrome 55 because Chrove versions 54+ do not support Shoutcast 1 HTTP protocol anymore (https://www.internet-radio.com/community/threads/latest-chrome-browser-update-v55-breaks-shoutcast-v1-x-html5-players.27560/)

Solutions:

1. The best solution for now is upgrading to Shoutcast version 2.
2. Another solution is to use patched Shoutcast 1 binaries available here: http://saynotolinux.com/shoutcast/

Comment: Perfect! I have asked them to upgrade it for me. Thanks Alexey.